# An error appears: cannot resolve postDelayed

Tags: android

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("runnable has run","a second must have passed");
    }
};
handler.post(run);
```

When I write this code, this error appears:

> cannot resolve`postDelayed.

Please tell me how to remove it.

Comment: There is no `postDelayed` in your code.. On which line you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put delay use this code.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // do something here
     }
}, 1000);
```